# "Englightening" Definition of Simple Lie Group

Tags: group-theory, terminology

I'm currently looking for an "englightening" definition of a simple Lie group, for someone who understands the terms Lie group/algebra already.

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group) definition is quite heavy

> In group theory, a simple Lie group is a connected non-abelian Lie group G which does not have nontrivial connected normal subgroups.

In contrast, for **finite** simple groups an often used analogy [is](https://books.google.de/books?id=aF5oAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=simple%20groups%20are%20the%20atoms%20of%20groups&source=bl&ots=7Xab3kK-7D&sig=m1e8cOzWDpDVz75TiryfbaZ4wM0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid_aTFmsTJAhXDcw8KHVuHCKcQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=simple%20groups%20are%20the%20atoms%20of%20groups&f=false)

> "simple groups are the atoms of finite groups."

[or](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~chris/groups/CHAP04%20First%20Steps%20in%20Group%20Theory.pdf)

> In a certain sense they’re the building blocks of all finite
>   groups but the term “simple” is deceptive. They’re not the most elementary of groups but
>   their simplicity refers to the fact that they can’t be pulled apart, in a certain way, into smaller
>   groups. They’re the atoms of the universe of finite groups.

Is there some similiar statement one can make about simple Lie groups?

Answer (score 1):

This is a definition made more for convenience than to capture some Platonic ideal of exactly the right concept. The point is more or less to guarantee that the Lie algebra is simple, which is really what one wants. Here the "atomic" theorem you want is [Levi decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_decomposition), which says that finite-dimensional Lie algebras are built from

1. [Solvable Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_Lie_algebra), which are in some sense all built from abelian Lie algebras, and
2. [Semisimple Lie algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra), which are built from simple Lie algebras in a very strong sense: namely, they are finite direct sums of simple Lie algebras.

It breaks the analogy to finite groups for $\mathbb{R}$ not to be regarded as a simple Lie algebra, but it just turns out that as you study Lie algebras more, $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't behave very much like the other simple Lie algebras.